# Query number of active staff by workspace and month

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what my source table would look like:

| Workspace | Username | Added Date | Deletion Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | STAFF 1 | 2020-12-01 | 9999-09-09 |
| ABC | STAFF 2 | 2020-12-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| EFG | STAFF 3 | 2020-12-01 | 9999-09-09 |
| EFG | STAFF 2 | 2021-01-02 | 9999-09-09 |

I am trying to query out the number of active staff by month and workspace.
So the end result should look something like the following:

| Workspace | Month | Number of Active Staff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Dec 2020 | 2 |
| ABC | Jan 2021 | 2 |
| EFG | Dec 2020 | 1 |
| EFG | Jan 2021 | 2 |

I'm using SQL studio 18 on Azure.
The query should include a date range filter. For example, I should be able to query number of active staff by month and workspace between Jan 2022 - May 2022 or a specific date.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_dates (
    ID int,
   M_start_date date,
    M_end_date date,months   
--Inserted the 12 month in this table:
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEMP_DATES]
          ([ID]
          ,[M_start_date]
          ,[M_end_date])
    VALUES
          (1,
          ‘2022-01-01’,
          ‘2022-01-31’)
-- n Repeated the above Until May 31, 2022
   
select count(distinct username), workspace_code, m_start_date,M_end_date from
workspace_staff
left join temp_dates on (added_date <= M_end_date and deletion_date >= M_start_date)
group by workspace_code, m_start_date,M_end_date
order by workspace_code, m_start_date,M_end_date
```

The insertion of the temp table was manual. I'm wondering if there's a better way to optimize this. We do not have a calendar table available in the DB.

Comment: what you have tried? please share your query.

Comment: Please provide DDL + DML commands

Comment: I wonder how you get your desired output? If we see from sample data, workspace ABC has no active staff in Jan 2021, and for EFG, Jan 2021 should have only one staff in active, isn't

Comment: ABC has active staff in Jan 2021 (Staff 1 and 2). Staff 2 included since the deletion date is Jan 1st. Vice versa for EFG. The deletion date for both staff is 9999-09-09 means they're active in Jan 2021.

Comment: Oh ya, sorry, I overlook date of deletion

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd think of this is rather than looking at what Workplace data you have I start with creating my date ranges, then from there I work out what staff I have in the month.

Here's how I recreated your Workspace table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Workspace;
CREATE TABLE #Workspace (Workspace VARCHAR(3), Username VARCHAR(7), AddedDate DATE, DeletionDate DATE)
INSERT INTO #Workspace (Workspace, Username, AddedDate, DeletionDate)
VALUES ('ABC', 'Staff 1', '2020-12-01', '9999-09-09'),
       ('ABC', 'Staff 2', '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01'),
       ('EFG', 'Staff 3', '2020-12-01', '9999-09-09'),
       ('EFG', 'Staff 2', '2021-01-02', '9999-09-09')
```

I wanted to create a temporary table with all the months required, and their start and end dates. I made a recursive CTE then used that to populate a temp table called #Dates:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2020-12-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2021-01-01';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Dates;
CREATE TABLE #Dates (ID INT IDENTITY, MonthStart DATE, MonthEnd DATE);

WITH CTE_Recur
AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate, EOMONTH(@StartDate) AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CTE_Recur.StartDate), EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CTE_Recur.StartDate))
    FROM CTE_Recur 
    WHERE CTE_Recur.StartDate < @EndDate
)

INSERT INTO #Dates (MonthStart, MonthEnd) SELECT * FROM CTE_Recur;
```

With both of these tables set up I then started from #Dates and joined to #Workspace  using the MonthStart and MonthEnd compared to the AddedDate and DeletionDate. These comparisons can be adjusted if you need to exclude someone who left on the 1st of a month by changing the >= to > etc.:

```
SELECT D.MonthStart,
       D.MonthEnd,
       FORMAT(D.MonthStart, 'MMM yyyy') AS MonthYearLabel,
       W.Workspace,
       COUNT(1) AS NumberOfActiveStaff
FROM #Dates AS D
     INNER JOIN #Workspace AS W ON W.AddedDate <= D.MonthEnd AND W.DeletionDate >= D.MonthStart
GROUP BY FORMAT(D.MonthStart, 'MMM yyyy'),
         D.ID,
         D.MonthStart,
         D.MonthEnd,
         W.Workspace
ORDER BY W.Workspace,
         MonthYearLabel;
```